# Как изменить имя поля во вложенном документе в MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Имеется такая структура документа:

```
{
    "_id" : 12421,
    "first" : {
        "second" : {
            "someFields" : 31241,
            "third" : [ 
                {
                    "wrongFieldName" : {
                        "something" : 2134214
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "wrongFieldName" : {
                        "something" : 23413
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Я хочу изменить все "wrongFieldName" на "rightFieldName":

```
{
    "_id" : 12421,
    "first" : {
        "second" : {
            "someFields" : 31241,
            "third" : [ 
                {
                    "rightFieldName" : {
                        "something" : 2134214
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "rightFieldName" : {
                        "something" : 23413
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Я пытался использовать $rename:

```
db.coll.update({"first.second.third.$.wrongFieldName" : { $exists: 1 }},
            { $rename : { "first.second.third.$.wrongFieldName" : "first.second.third.rightFieldName" } } )
```

Но из-за того, что изменяемые поля находятся в массиве, запрос не выполняется, вылетает ошибка:

```
The source field for $rename may not be dynamic: first.second.third.$.wrongFieldName
```

Comment: Вы на русском stackoverflow

Comment: Хмм, точно :) спасибо